# Error 1452 thrown, while parent rows exist

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm getting 1452 error (below) on `INSERT`, but it doesn't make sense.

**The tables:**

```
# Has parent field
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price_comp_group` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`headline` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`text` TEXT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

# Has child field
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price_comp_group_drug` (
`group_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`drug_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`item_order` INT(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `fk_group_id_drug` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `price_comp_group`(`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_drug_id_drug` FOREIGN KEY (`drug_id`) REFERENCES `drug`(`ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

# Unique index
ALTER TABLE `price_comp_group_drug`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_group_drug
(`group_id`, `drug_id`);
```

Now, I'm trying to do such multiple insert:

```
INSERT INTO `price_comp_group_drug` (`group_id`, `drug_id`, `item_order`)
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (0, 3, 6);
```

and I get this:

**#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dev23_db`.`price_comp_group_drug`, CONSTRAINT `fk_group_id_drug` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `price_comp_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)**

- Group of id = 1 **exists**.
- Drugs of IDs = 1, 2, 3 **exist**.

So why am I seeing this error? I should see it if I tried to insert/update row with `FOREIGN KEY` value that **does not** have a parent...

Comment: Can you please put drug table create table sql?

Comment: Where is your price_comp_group table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In insert statement provided by you foreign key can not be zero.

In insert statement in third row 'group_id' is specified as '0'.

As there is a foreign key on group_id it is throwing an error.

Comment: But isn't this zero supposed to be first value of `item_order` column? The `group_id` values are in the first bracket: (1, 1, 1). Or am I wrong?

Comment: OH MY GOD.... I get it. You're absolutely right. I did not get the multiple insert syntax. Thank you!